# regex ~ delimited string is getting confused when it sees ~~ and skips a column

Tags: regex

I am trying to split string with REGEXP in Oracle (it has a regex function that uses the normal syntax) with ~ separated string into different columns. This almost works but when when two ~~ are next to each other it seems to get confused.

```
Dataset
1 2 3 456 7  
A~B~X~~ ~4~5

REGEXP_SUBSTR('A~B~X~~ ~4~5','[^~]+',1,3) column_3 = X
REGEXP_SUBSTR('A~B~X~~ ~4~5','[^~]+',1,4) column_4 Should be null
REGEXP_SUBSTR('A~B~X~~ ~4~5','[^~]+',1,5) column_5 = space
REGEXP_SUBSTR('A~B~X~~ ~4~5','[^~]+',1,6) column_6 = 4
REGEXP_SUBSTR('A~B~X~~ ~4~5','[^~]+',1,7) column_7 = 5
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can't test now, but try `REGEXP_SUBSTR('A~B~X~~ ~4~5','([^~]*)(~|$)',1,4, NULL, 1)`

Comment: That seems to do the job, thank you for your help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use

```
REGEXP_SUBSTR('A~B~X~~ ~4~5','([^~]*)(~|$)',1,4, NULL, 1)
```

The regex will match *zero* or more (due to `*` quantifier) chars other than `~` and will require `~` or end of string on the right. Due to the last `1` argument you will only get Group 1 value.

You might also consider appending `~` to the col value, and then use `([^~]*)~`:

```
REGEXP_SUBSTR('A~B~X~~ ~4~5' || '~','([^~]*)~',1,4, NULL, 1)
```